# php sql pdo return results grouped by a field?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have a query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, loyalty_num  
FROM logs WHERE loyalty_num != '' 
  and loyalty_num is not null  
  and store != 000  
  and loyalty_num not like '000%'
```

i'm using PDO in php and using default fetch mode fetch assoc. is it possible to have the data returned with `fetchAll()` so that each key of the results is a `loyalty_num` and contains the other records `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: Please post a sample table of how you want the query output to look. From what it sounds like though, not you can't make PDO do it on its own. You need to fetch and then modify the array.

Comment: Any comment on this? Does it meet your need?

Comment: the solution was using `$stmt->execute(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: You should post your own answer below then.